# Actor shakes when it is near the destination Vector2

Tags: java, libgdx

The issue is when the Actor/Entity moves towards the click position, as its about 1 tile away the character starts shaking as in it moves up 7 pixels, then moves down 7 pixels over and over not reaching the destination.

I've tried a few different methods but all seem to end in the same way, it might be possible it only needs to go up a few pixels but since the speed is 7 it moves too far, then moves back.

```
if (Objects.nonNull(next)) {
            if (this.getDistanceVector(next) <= 64) {
                return;
            }

            double destX = next.y*64 - this.getX();
            double destY = next.x*64 - this.getY();

            double dist = Math.sqrt(destX * destX + destY * destY);
            destX = destX / dist;
            destY = destY / dist;

            double travelX = (destX * speed);
            double travelY = (destY * speed);

            this.moveBy((float) travelX, (float)travelY);
        } else {
            moveTo = null;
        }
```

It should walk to the position and stop, it currently walks close then shakes on the x axis or the y axis depending on location of click.

Comment: So it has a destination x. It starts at like x - 2, then moves up to x + 5, then back to x - 2? (Example?)

Comment: Let's call speed, pixels per frame or p/f. Let's simply call distance pixels. if speed p/f is greater than distance, then that means it will over shoot. If it is going 100 pixels per frame and it only needs to move 1 pixel, then it will overshoot by 99 pixels. Instead, if that occurs, simply on that iteration, force set the position to the destination. In other words, if (speed > distance){ this.setX(destX); this.setY(destY); In general, you can say that if it is guaranteed to pass the destination, set it to the destination.

Comment: That works i guess but its very snappy, what im doing now is when speed > distance, to use a smooth transition in stead of a set, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the speed is greater then distance, i was able to make a smooth transition without any jitter.

```
if (speed > dist) {
                destX = target.y - this.getX();
                destY = target.x - this.getY();

                destX = destX / dist;
                destY = destY / dist;

                double travelX = (destX * speed);
                double travelY = (destY * speed);

                this.setX((int)travelX);
                this.setY((int)travelY);
            } else {
                destX = destX / dist;
                destY = destY / dist;

                double travelX = (destX * speed);
                double travelY = (destY * speed);

                this.moveBy((float) travelX, (float)travelY);
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain how you did the smooth transition? I assume by snappy, you mean just "teleporting".

Comment: Don't forget Stack Overflow encourages people to mark its own answer as the correct, there's nothing wrong with it since it solved your problem.